# Excel 2 Monitors Remove from Docking Station

Tags: multiple-monitors

I work on Excel on **two monitors** when I am at my docking station.

I removed my laptop from the docking station and now I am **not** able to access the Excel files that were open on the 2nd monitor.

I can see them when I hover over excel but I cannot pull them up on the laptop screen.

Is there a way to get it on my laptop/main screen without having to go back to the docking station to access the 2nd monitor?

Comment: From Display settings choose "Show only 1st (or) 2nd monitor" to change your view to the secondary monitor. Save and close your excel file. Change back to the main screen and open the excel file again.

Comment: When I go to display settings, the only monitor available is the mobile pc display.  I don't have the option to choose the secondary monitor.

Comment: Oh... you're right. :) answer below

Comment: This is likely not an Excel problem and more of an OS issue. What OS are you using? Also, has it ever worked for you to undock your laptop with documents open on the secondary monitor?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and no I have not been able to access them when I leave the docking station with them open on the secondary monitor.  Unfortunately I forget on occasion to close or move them from the secondary monitor and then I am stuck with them open and unable to access them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

A quick and easy trick to move windows that you can't access is to do the following:

- Hover over the application in the taskbar
- When the preview pops up, right-click on it and select **Move**
- Press any of the arrow buttons on the keyboard (this causes the window to move a little)
- Now use the mouse, and the window will "snap" to where the mouse pointer currently is

If the Move option is greyed out, it might be because the window is maximized or minimized. Then click on **Restore** first, and repeat the steps.

**Option 2**

Select the troubling window with `Alt + Tab` and then press `Win + Left` until the window is moved to the correct monitor.

Comment: Unfortunately the move button is greyed out and I am not able to change it.  I tried to restore but that does not seem to change the sheet that was on the secondary monitor.

Comment: Did you right-click on the correct sheet?

Comment: Yes.  I right clicked on the correct sheet and it does not allow me to restore or move it.

Comment: What version of Excel and what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: windows 7 professional and excel 2010

Comment: Perhaps it works differently. Try to press `Alt + Tab` until the hidden sheet is active. Then press `Win + Left` to move it to the other screen.

Comment: I had wrote the same answer but deleted mine as after posting noted you had added the same solution in the comment :)

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering where it went.. :) I updated my answer to have both solutions.